# Curl cannot resolve host - works on Windows but not on Ubuntu for Windows

Tags: bash, curl

I run a bash shell on Ubuntu from Windows 10. I was recently provisioned a new laptop  and now find that I am unable to resolve URL's with curl that work when I run the curl directly on Windows (as opposed to on ubuntu bash running on windows 10).
As per below though running it on wget works even on ubuntu for windows.

```
root@ionwuka2go2:/mnt/c/home# curl https://basex.org
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: basex.org
root@ionwuka2go2:/mnt/c/home# wget --spider https://basex.org
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2021-02-13 09:23:33--  https://basex.org/
Resolving basex.org (basex.org)... 185.221.106.187
Connecting to basex.org (basex.org)|185.221.106.187|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 14364 (14K) [text/html]
Remote file exists and could contain further links,
but recursion is disabled -- not retrieving.
```

Comment: It's not obvious but I think you'll get an answer on https://superuser.com/

The programs use different resolving techniques if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Caused by running anti-malware software

Comment: Why anti-malware caused problem to `curl`, but not to `wget` ?